# How can I use FBJS to prompt users to post feed in facebook?

Tags: api, facebook, fbjs

Tried sth like below and nth happens-

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
   FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ 
       FB.Facebook.init("<?=$apiKey?>", "channel/xd_receiver.htm"); 
       var api = FB.Facebook.apiClient;
       Facebook.streamPublish();    
   }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Facebook.streamPublish();
```

String can be inputed as parameters. The string being the message the user enters for the post at the time of publication.

But there are also several other parameters that can be inputed, I would suggest reading more [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook.streamPublish).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have coded as following and nth happens, wht is probably wrong for this?

<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ 
 FB.Facebook.init("<?=$apiKey?>", "channel/xd_receiver.htm"); 
        var api = FB.Facebook.apiClient;  
        Facebook.streamPublish();
});